# What information should be on a Sorcerer's spell sheet?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, sorcerer, character-sheets

I am working on a custom spell sheet for the sorcerer class. The sheet is meant to be suitable for an intermediate or advanced player who understands sorcerer spell casting but has not memorized every table. I intend for this spell sheet to have everything that the player needs to keep track of their casting, entirely supplanting the tiny spell section on the back of the standard character sheet.

The sheet currently contains the following information:

- Spells Known. For each spell:

  - Spell name
  - Level at which the sorcerer gains that spells known slot.
  - Page reference.
  - Checkboxes for verbal/somatic/material/other components.
- A copy of the spells-per-day table from the SRD and the bonus spells table.
- Checkboxes for spells-per-day for each level.
- DC modifier (i.e. DC = level + X).
- Spaces for short, medium, and long ranges, and the formulas for calculating them.
- Space for costly material components and foci.
- Space for metamagic feats and adjustments.
- Spaces for notes.

My question, then: what information would you like or expect to see on the sheet? What would make the player's life easier? Are there any mistakes or pitfalls that I should avoid?

(When it's done, I can send the completed sheet to anyone who's interested. I am not aware of a way to upload it here, though.)

Comment: What constitutes a good balance between a clean sheet and enough information is very subjective and not a good fit for this Q&A format. It's entirely subjective. For example, in my games I almost never need the school for most spells. And for those where the DM wants to know, we all know the schools without looking it up.

Comment: @nvoigt It’s subjective, but I’m not convinced it’s *purely* or *primarily* opinion-based. Answerers can cite experience – sheets they have used that swamped them with data and made it hard to find information, sheets they have used that were missing important details they wound up having to look up often, etc. Comparisons can be made to various different sheets out there. I think there’s enough to make this a valid question.

Comment: It's explicitly polling for what people would like or think it should have, though. There might be a question on this subject that isn't primarily opinion-based, but this one isn't it. This might be fixable if those criteria can be replaced, and votes to hold are the tool to ensure that happens before it attracts bad answers.

Comment: @KRyan Take me as an example. The "perfect" sheet varied in the last 25 years. 25 years ago I would have made another sheet than 10 years ago or five years ago or last year. And *all* of them would have been valid answers. They weren't *wrong*, they were just subjective.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie That’s true; that should be edited to make it more specifically requiring appropriate backing up, along the lines of BS/GS.